# Given a number,can we find out the **number of edges** in its divisor lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Given a number,can we find out the **number of edges** in its divisor lattice.for Finding the no of vertices we can maybe do it but how to find edges confused.
maybe we can do it while taking subsets

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples

Comment: Hint: write the prime factorization of your number $n$ as $n=p_1^{r_1} \ldots p_m^{r_m}$. Then $n$ is connected to $m$ integers below it in the divisor lattice. Sum over all divisors.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy Dover suggested in a comment, start from the prime factorization:

$$n=p_1^{r_1}\cdot p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$$

Concentrating on the exponents and writing them as a vector, you have $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_m)$ as the top element of your lattice, and you have $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ as the bottom element (representing the number $1$).

You have $(r_1+1)(r_2+1)\cdots(r_m+1)=\prod_{i=1}^m(r_i+1)$ vertices in between, since each coordinate can range from $0$ to $r_i$ inclusive.

You have an edge between any two vertices which differ by exactly a $1$ in the value of exactly $1$ coordinate. So if you fix coordinates $2$ through $m$, there are exactly $r_1$ such steps. How many ways are there to fix $2$ through $m$? That's again $\prod_{i=2}^m(r_i+1)$. So for this single (first) direction you have $r_1\cdot\prod_{i=2}^m(r_i+1)$ edges. Summing over all directions you get

$$\sum_{j=1}^m\left(r_j\cdot\prod_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq j}}^m(r_i+1)\right)=
\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\frac{r_j}{r_j+1}\cdot\prod_{i=1}^m(r_i+1)\right)$$

which you can write more easily as

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{r_j}{r_j+1}\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{i=1}^m(r_i+1)\right)$$

since the product does not depend on $j$.

Sanity checks:

- If the values of $r_i$ are all large, then $\frac{r_i}{r_i+1}\approx1$ so you get the number of edges approximately as the number of vertices times the number of directions. Makes sense since most vertices have one (directed) edge for each direction.
- If one of the $r_i$ is zero, nothing changes since the contribution to the sum is $0$ and the contribution to the product is $1$. Makes sense since it allows you to add more $p_{m+1}^0$ to the prime factorization without affecting the result.

Comment: Isn't that the same as $\sum_p\nu(n/p)$ where $\nu$ is the sum-of-divisors function and the sum is over the prime divisors $p$ of $n?$